# factory pattern in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have the following factory class, wonder if this code can be implemented in better way. I saw few discussions about spring factory bean, but don't find good examples.

```
@service
public CustomerSearchFactory{
  @Autowired
  private CustomerSearchByID searchById;
  @Autowired
  private CustomerSearchByName searcyByName;
  @Autowired
  private CustomerSearchBySSN searchBySSN;

  public CustomerSearch getInstance(Request param){
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(param.getID()){
        return searchById;
    }else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(param.getName()){
        return searcyByName;
    }else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(param.getSSN()){
        return searchBySSN;
    }
  }  
}

@service
public CustomerSearchByID implements CustomerSearch{
  @Autowired
  private Service1 service1;  
  public Response search(Request request){
   --
   -- 
   ReturnResponse rs = service1.performSearch(inputRequest);
   --
   return response;
 }  
}

@service
public CustomerSearchBySSN implements CustomerSearch{
  @Autowired
  private Service2 service2;  
  public Response search(Request request){
   --
   -- 
   ReturnResponse rs = service2.performSSNSearch(inputRequest);
   --enter code here`
   return response;
 }  
}
```

caller code:

```
CustomerSearch customerSearch= customerSearchFactory.getInstance(param)
response = customerSearch.search(request);
```

I am using the spring 3.1 framework and want to know if this code can be optimized.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise not to use a different `CustomerSearch` per search criteria.
As your functionality will evolve you could need a `CustomerSearch` that is using the country the `Customer` is from.
But what if you want to search on the `Country` in combination with part of the name?
Soon you will be combining different search criteria together which will require one smart `CustomerSearch` bean.

Comment: Malachi, The reason for having different customer search is to invoke different services. I don't think we will have another search in the application and the search can be done only on one criteria. let know if you have any suggestion.